# What's the usage of the stm32's CMSIS function NVIC_ClearPendingIRQ?

Tags: c, arm, embedded, stm32, microcontroller

When the program go into the external interrupt function, I can use *NVIC_SetPendingIRQ* to jump out to the main function. Then I use *NVIC_ClearPendingIRQ* in the main function, but I can't return back to the external interrupt function. So I want to know the right usage of it.

Comment: Are you talking about the EXTI callback function provided by HAL libraries? So the interrupt fires but execution doesn't fall into that callback function? Please provide more details and some code.

Comment: @Tagli I just want to know the usage of _Interrupt set pending Registers_ and _Interrupt clear pending Registers_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An interrupt can be (1) pending or not pending, (2) active or not active and (3) enabled or not enabled.

Pending means queued up to run.

Active mean running now (or was running but got pre-empted by a higher priority nested interrupt).

Enabled means that it can go from pending to active automatically.

If an interrupt is enabled and you call NVIC_SetPendingIRQ from the main context you have changed the state to "not active and pending", but this state is immediately changed by hardware to "active and not pending".

While the interrupt is active it can be triggered again either by hardware or software, in this case it would be "both active and pending" (ie: running and queued up to run again).

If you return from the interrupt function while you are active and pending then you will immediately jump back to the start of the same interrupt function again (assuming that no higher priority interrupt was also pending)  but now you will be "active and not pending".

If you are active and pending but don't want to run the interrupt function twice, you can call NVIC_ClearPendingIRQ before you return from the interrupt function.

Comment: Tom did you mean "not active and not pending" ? Or am I mistaken?

Comment: I've just re-read the answer and I think it is correct throughout.  Which paragraph do you think is wrong?

Comment: ...but this state is immediately changed by hardware to "active and not pending".

Comment: @Sorenp , *active and not pending* is a valid state, meaning that core is currently executing ISR of that interrupt, but there is no other interrupt waiting (pending) of the same type.

Comment: I just want to know the right usage of the pending registers. Your answer is too complex.

Comment: @jyygxxf : you don't normally need to use them at all.  The circumstances where you might are both unusual and complex.  This answer is as simple as it can be.  Don't sweat it; if it becomes appropriate to use them, you'll know